# i can't read an excel that i could already read in R, i'm using the tool read.xlsx2

Tags: java, r, onedrive, r-xlsx

I'm using R and i need to open an excel file, while i'm working with it it appears the next message:
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Z", "hasField", .jcast(x, "java/lang/Object"),  :
RcallMethod: cannot determine object class
The function that i'm using is read.xlsx2 from the package xlsx.

I´m having this problem since i linked my desktop with onedrive (R didn't found the files), i tried unlinking my desktop, but i had the same problem (didn't found) (and i changed the directory of the function). Then, i changed the directory of the excel and obtained this message:

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Z", "hasField", .jcast(x, "java/lang/Object"),  :
RcallMethod: cannot determine object class

Comment: Does this happen with only this file or with all .xlsx files? And does it still happen if you put this file in a directory that is not on one drive?

Comment: It happens with all .xlsx files, when the file is in a directory that is on the one drive, R doesn't find it. When i put the file in desktop or other directory that is not on drive, it appears the .jcall error.